# Unable to assign the value to structure member using double pointer

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program that implements a basic character sheet with an inventory. User
will be able to create a character, view their info, add items, and view items.

There are functions for each functionality.

I created a header file `charactersheet.h` to define structure and function inside it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Item {
    char *name;
    int price;
    double weight;
};

struct Inventory {
    struct Item **item;
    int numitems;
};

struct Character {
    char *name;
    int Level;
    long XP;
    struct Inventory inventory;
};

void
createCharacter(struct Character *c)
{
    printf("Enter Name:");
    c->name = (char *) malloc(40 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s", c->name);
    printf("Enter Level:");
    scanf("%d", &c->Level);
    printf("Enter XP:");
    scanf("%ld", &c->XP);
}

void
viewCharacter(struct Character *b)
{
    printf("%s level %d with %ld XP", b->name, b->Level, b->XP);
}

void
addItem(struct Inventory *i)
{
    i->numitems = i->numitems + 1;
    printf("Enter name:");
    scanf("%s", i->item[i->numitems]->name);
    printf("Enter price:");
    scanf("%d", &(i->item[i->numitems]->price));
    printf("Enter Weight:");
    scanf("%d", &(i->item[i->numitems]->weight));
}

void
viewItem(struct Inventory i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i.numitems; j++)
        printf("%s,%d golds,%.2lf pounds", i.item[j]->name, i.item[j]->price, i.item[j]->weight);
}
```

The `addItem` function takes `Inventory *` function as input reallocate the memory to accommodate the additional item.
The `viewItem` function takes Inventory as parameter and list all items.
Now in the file `charactersheet.c` I have following implementation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "charsheet.h"

int
main(void)
{

    struct Item items;
    struct Inventory inventory;
    struct Character chars;

    inventory.numitems = 0;

    while (1) {
        char choice;

        printf("\nC Create character\n");
        printf("V view Character\n");
        printf("A Add Item\n");
        printf("I view Items\n");
        printf("Q Quit\n");

        scanf(" %c", &choice);
        switch (choice) {

        case 'C':
            createCharacter(&chars);
            break;

        case 'V':
            viewCharacter(&chars);
            break;

        case 'A':
            addItem(&inventory);
            break;

        case 'I':
            viewItem(inventory);
            break;

        case 'Q':
            exit(0);

        default:
            printf("Invalid input\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However I am not able to implement `addItem` and `viewItem` functions. There are no errors in the code in my editor as well.

Comment: 1) Please reduce to [mcve]. 2) Please indent your code. 3) Do *not* define function in header files (only declare)

Comment: This is already the third question today with some "inventory" variable and double pointers.

Comment: You're not allocating memory anywhere for the `struct Item **items;`, nor are you allocating memory for the items themselves.

Comment: You need to initialize `inventory.item = NULL;`. In `addItem` you can use `realloc` to reallocate the memory for `i->item`, something like: `struct Inventory *t = realloc(i->item, sizeof(*i) * i->numitems);` `if (t == NULL) { /* some error handling here */ }` `i->item = t;`.

Comment: @IanAbbott don't I need to allocate before reallocating.I am stuck what to allocate and reallocate? can you clear it

Comment: @IcanCode The old pointer value passed to `realloc` is allowed to be null, in which case it behaves the same as `malloc`.

Comment: In your code, it seems that you want to manage only one single character. Is it really want you want?

Comment: @SergeBallesta yes i only want a single character.

Comment: _Side note:_ Although it works in your case because you have only _one_ `.c` that includes your `.h` file, you should not put full function definitions in the `.h` file. _If_ you had _two_ [or more] `.c` files, this would produce _duplicate_ symbol definitions for the functions. In general, just put the function _prototype_ in the `.h` file (e.g. `void createCharacter(struct Character *c);`) and _not_ the entire function definition. The function body should, then, go into a single `.c` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a number of issues.

In the `Inventory` struct, you [proably] want `*item` instead of `**item`. The double pointer made things needlessly complicated.

In `addItem`, you need to do a `realloc` on `item` to increase the length of the array before trying to fill in the data.

If we *still* had the `**item`, this would have required an *additional* `malloc` for each new struct.

In `addItem`, you were doing a `scanf` for `name`, but were not allocating it, so that was UB. Better to do the `scanf` on a fixed buffer and then use `strdup`.

In `createCharacter`, you're doing a fixed `malloc` of length 40. Better to use a [large] fixed size buffer and then do `strdup`

In `viewItem`, you were passing the struct *by value*. While that's legal, most of the time, you want to pass a pointer to the struct instead.

---

Here's some refactored code. I used preprocessor conditionals to show your/old vs. my/new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif
```

Anyway, here is the `.h` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Item {
    char *name;
    int price;
    double weight;
};

struct Inventory {
#if 0
    struct Item **item;
#else
    struct Item *item;
#endif
    int numitems;
};

struct Character {
    char *name;
    int Level;
    long XP;
    struct Inventory inventory;
};
```

Here is the `.c` file. As per my top comments, I moved the function bodies here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "charsheet.h"

void
createCharacter(struct Character *c)
{

    printf("Enter Name:");
#if 0
    c->name = (char *) malloc(40 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s", c->name);
#else
    char buf[1000];
    scanf("%s",buf);
    c->name = strdup(buf);
#endif

    printf("Enter Level:");
    scanf("%d", &c->Level);

    printf("Enter XP:");
    scanf("%ld", &c->XP);
}

void
viewCharacter(struct Character *b)
{
    printf("%s level %d with %ld XP\n", b->name, b->Level, b->XP);
}

void
addItem(struct Inventory *i)
{

    i->numitems = i->numitems + 1;

#if 0
    printf("Enter name:");
    scanf("%s", i->item[i->numitems]->name);

    printf("Enter price:");
    scanf("%d", &(i->item[i->numitems]->price));

    printf("Enter Weight:");
    scanf("%d", &(i->item[i->numitems]->weight));
#else
    struct Item *t;

    t = realloc(i->item,sizeof(*t) * i->numitems);
    if (t == NULL) {
        perror("item");
        exit(1);
    }

    i->item = t;

    t += i->numitems - 1;

    char buf[1000];
    printf("Enter name:");
    scanf("%s", buf);
    t->name = strdup(buf);

    printf("Enter price:");
    scanf("%d", &t->price);

    printf("Enter Weight:");
    scanf("%d", &t->weight);
#endif
}

#if 0
void
viewItem(struct Inventory i)
#else
void
viewItem(struct Inventory *i)
#endif
{

    for (int j = 0; j < i->numitems; j++) {
        struct Item *t = &i->item[j];
        printf("%s,%d golds,%.2lf pounds\n",
            t->name, t->price, t->weight);
    }
}

int
main(void)
{

    struct Item items;
    struct Inventory inventory;
    struct Character chars;

    inventory.numitems = 0;
#if 1
    inventory.item = NULL;
#endif

#if 1
    setbuf(stdout,NULL);
#endif

    while (1) {
        char choice;

        printf("\nC Create character\n");
        printf("V view Character\n");
        printf("A Add Item\n");
        printf("I view Items\n");
        printf("Q Quit\n");

        scanf(" %c", &choice);
        switch (choice) {

        case 'C':
            createCharacter(&chars);
            break;

        case 'V':
            viewCharacter(&chars);
            break;

        case 'A':
            addItem(&inventory);
            break;

        case 'I':
#if 0
            viewItem(inventory);
#else
            viewItem(&inventory);
#endif
            break;

        case 'Q':
            exit(0);
            break;

        default:
            printf("Invalid input\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> what if i need **item?

Well, I think you should have some justification for the extra complexity. But, if it's a requirement, it is possible.

Also, the `scanf` for `weight` was using the *wrong* format. If you had enabled warnings by compiling with `-Wall` [which you should *always* do], the compiler would have flagged this for you.

Here's the code with code for double pointers. Note that I've merged the `.h` into the `.c` here for brevity:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef DOUBLE_POINTER
#define DOUBLE_POINTER      0
#endif

struct Item {
    char *name;
    int price;
    double weight;
};

struct Inventory {
#if DOUBLE_POINTER
    struct Item **item;
#else
    struct Item *item;
#endif
    int numitems;
};

struct Character {
    char *name;
    int Level;
    long XP;
    struct Inventory inventory;
};

void
createCharacter(struct Character *c)
{

    printf("Enter Name:");
#if 0
    c->name = (char *) malloc(40 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s", c->name);
#else
    char buf[1000];
    scanf("%s",buf);
    c->name = strdup(buf);
#endif

    printf("Enter Level:");
    scanf("%d", &c->Level);

    printf("Enter XP:");
    scanf("%ld", &c->XP);
}

void
viewCharacter(struct Character *b)
{
    printf("%s level %d with %ld XP\n", b->name, b->Level, b->XP);
}

void
addItem(struct Inventory *i)
{

    i->numitems = i->numitems + 1;

#if 0
    printf("Enter name:");
    scanf("%s", i->item[i->numitems]->name);

    printf("Enter price:");
    scanf("%d", &(i->item[i->numitems]->price));

    printf("Enter Weight:");
    scanf("%d", &(i->item[i->numitems]->weight));
#else
    struct Item *t;

    i->item = realloc(i->item,sizeof(*i->item) * i->numitems);
    if (i->item == NULL) {
        perror("item");
        exit(1);
    }

#if DOUBLE_POINTER
    t = malloc(sizeof(*t));
    i->item[i->numitems - 1] = t;
#else
    t = &i->item[i->numitems - 1];
#endif

    char buf[1000];
    printf("Enter name:");
    scanf("%s", buf);
    t->name = strdup(buf);

    printf("Enter price:");
    scanf("%d", &t->price);

    printf("Enter Weight:");
#if 0
    scanf("%d", &t->weight);
#else
    scanf("%lf", &t->weight);
#endif
#endif
}

#if 0
void
viewItem(struct Inventory i)
#else
void
viewItem(struct Inventory *i)
#endif
{

    for (int j = 0; j < i->numitems; j++) {
#if DOUBLE_POINTER
        struct Item *t = i->item[j];
#else
        struct Item *t = &i->item[j];
#endif
        printf("%s,%d golds,%.2lf pounds\n",
            t->name, t->price, t->weight);
    }
}

int
main(void)
{

#if 0
    struct Item items;
#endif
    struct Inventory inventory;
    struct Character chars;

    inventory.numitems = 0;
#if 1
    inventory.item = NULL;
#endif

#if 1
    setbuf(stdout,NULL);
#endif

    while (1) {
        char choice;

        printf("\nC Create character\n");
        printf("V view Character\n");
        printf("A Add Item\n");
        printf("I view Items\n");
        printf("Q Quit\n");

        scanf(" %c", &choice);
        switch (choice) {

        case 'C':
            createCharacter(&chars);
            break;

        case 'V':
            viewCharacter(&chars);
            break;

        case 'A':
            addItem(&inventory);
            break;

        case 'I':
#if 0
            viewItem(inventory);
#else
            viewItem(&inventory);
#endif
            break;

        case 'Q':
            exit(0);
            break;

        default:
            printf("Invalid input\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what if i need **item?

Comment: Perfectly done :) when will I be able to write such a code

Answer (score 1):

> The addItem function takes Inventory * function as input reallocate the memory to accommodate the additional item

Well, it could but it does not

```
void addItem(struct Inventory* i){
i->numitems =i->numitems + 1;
printf("Enter name:");
scanf("%s",i->item[i->numitems]->name);
printf("Enter price:");
scanf("%d",&(i->item[i->numitems]->price));
printf("Enter Weight:");
scanf("%d",&(i->item[i->numitems]->weight));
}
```

`Inventory` is a `struct`, an array of `numitems` pointers to `item`

You need to build it carefully. They would not come to life just by adding 1 to a counter.

Some things you may consider

- As pointed already in the comments, INDENT your code
- Use typedef to name your structs
- Use a convention to `struct` naming, like first letter in uppercase **only** for structs
- When you declare `Item **item`; you are declaring `item`, so write `Item** item` instead. This way makes clear what is what and no one needs to search for asterisks around names in declarations. `item` is `Item**`, `*item` is `Item*` and `**item` points to the first `Item`.
- do not return `void`. In general is a waste of something, maybe an error
- use `menu()` as a function to return the user option
- do not use `scanf()`: it has another purpose: scan formatted input. But when you use always test the return. `scanf()` return an `int`. Read the manual.
- do not put code or declare variables in a header: use another file with the same name as your header and put your code there
- leave `main()` in another file so you can have many test programs to test your set of functions...
- do not mix logic and data entry in the same function: it creates a bad dependency and limits your testing capabilities.
- also see things like this

```
void addItem(Inventory*);
```

`addItem()` adds an item to an inventory. Write

```
int    addItem( item Item*, Inventory* inv);
```

And maybe return 0 for ok or an error code, but pass pointers to `Item` and `Inventory`. It is clearer and more manageable...

- maybe you need another Inventory, a dynamic array of Character

#### A possible header

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct
{       
    char*   name;
    int     price;
    double  weight;

}   Item;


typedef struct
{
    Item**  item;
    int     size;

}   Inventory;


typedef struct
{
    Inventory   inventory;
    int         level;
    char*       name;
    long        xp;

 }  Character;


typedef struct
{
    Character**  item;
    int          limit;
    int          size;

}   Cast;

int         addItem(Item*, Inventory*);
Cast*       buildCast(unsigned);
Character*  createCharacter(Character*);
int         viewCharacter(Character*);
int         viewItem(Inventory*);
```

Using `typedef` to the structs, a convention that first letter in uppercase means a struct name, and a `Cast` struct to hold the `Character` set.

I am adding a `buildCast()` that shows the usual way to build this sort of thing, the same thing the system does for every program building `argc` and `argv` as

```
int main( int argc, char** argv)
```

```
typedef struct
{
    Character**  item;
    int          limit;
    int          size;

}   Cast;
```

You can write

```
Cast*       buildCast(unsigned count)
{
    // builds an array of 'count' pointers
    // to 'Character'
    if( count == 0 ) return NULL;
    Cast* one = (Cast*) malloc(sizeof(Cast));
    one->limit = count;
    one->size= 0; // empty
    one->item = (Character**) malloc( count * sizeof(Character*));
    for( int i =0; i<count; i+= 1)
        one->item[i] = NULL;
    return one;
}
```

And call as in

```
    Cast* cast = buildCast(300);
```

To have an array of 300-max pointers to `Character` initially empty

This is just an example using your code and has errors as I did not correct the issues on memory allocation, for example.
You can look at `buildCast()` and see how to build your inventory struct.

I will left a set of files here that you can compile and run and move on if you decided to go this way. It is just your code refactored.

**1 of 3 soch.h header:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct
{       
    char*   name;
    int     price;
    double  weight;

}   Item;


typedef struct
{
    Item**  item;
    int     size;

}   Inventory;


typedef struct
{
    Inventory   inventory;
    int         level;
    char*       name;
    long        xp;

 }  Character;


typedef struct
{
    Character**  item;
    int          limit;
    int          size;

}   Cast;

int         addItem(Item*, Inventory*);
Cast*       buildCast(unsigned);
Character*  createCharacter(Character*);
char        menu();
int         viewCharacter(Character*);
int         viewItem(Inventory*);
```

**2 of 3 sohc.c functions**

```
#include"soch.h"


int addItem(Item* it, Inventory* inv)
{
    printf("Enter name:");
    scanf("%s",it->name);
    printf("Enter price:");
    scanf("%d",&(it->price));
    printf("Enter Weight:");
    scanf("%lf",&(it->weight));
    inv->item[inv->size] = it;
    inv->size =inv->size + 1;
    return 0;
}


Cast*       buildCast(unsigned count)
{
    // builds an array of 'count' pointers
    // to 'Character'
    if( count == 0 ) return NULL;
    Cast* one = (Cast*) malloc(sizeof(Cast));
    one->limit = count;
    one->size= 0; // empty
    one->item = (Character**) malloc( count * sizeof(Character*));
    for( int i =0; i<count; i+= 1)
        one->item[i] = NULL;
    return one;
}


Character* createCharacter(Character* c)
{
    Character* one = NULL;
    printf("Enter Name:");
    c->name = (char*) malloc(40*sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s",c->name);
    printf("Enter Level:");
    scanf("%d",&c->level);
    printf("Enter XP:");
    scanf("%ld",&c->xp);
    return one;
}


char        menu()
{
    char    choice[30];
    printf("\nC Create character\n");
    printf("V view Character\n");
    printf("A Add Item\n");
    printf("I view Items\n");
    printf("Q Quit\n");
    fgets( choice, sizeof(choice), stdin);
    return choice[0];
};


int viewCharacter(Character* b)
{
    printf("%s level %d with %ld XP",
        b->name,
        b->level,
        b->xp);
    return 0;
}

int viewItem(Inventory* i)
{
    for(int j=0; j<i->size; j++)
    {
        printf( 
            "%s,%d golds,%.2lf pounds\n",
            i->item[j]->name,
            i->item[j]->price,
            i->item[j]->weight);
    };
    return 0;
}
```

**main function to test `buildCast()` and `menu()`**

```
 #include "soch.h"

int main(void)
{
    Inventory   inventory;
    Item        item;
    Character   chars;

    Cast* cast = buildCast(300);

    while(1)
    {
        switch(menu())
        {
        case 'C':
            createCharacter(&chars);
            break;

        case 'V':
            viewCharacter(&chars);
            break;

        case 'A':
            addItem(&item, &inventory);
            break;

        case'I':
            viewItem(&inventory);
            break;

        case 'Q':
            exit(0);

        default:
            printf("Invalid input\n");
            break;
        };  // switch()
    };  // while()
    return 0;
};
```

In practice you would build structs like `Inventory` in blocks of `N` pointers, for efficiency, and if needed call `realloc()` when more pointers are needed. But for a simple program you can write a fixed array of pointers or `malloc()` one by one and see how it goes.

Write back if you choose to go this way. Take a look at the provided code